# Hide last items in list with css

Tags: css

I will hide the first items in a "list". 
Example: I have 100 Items, but i will only show the FIRST 25 Items. How can i make this with CSS? to hide all from 26+

Items look like this

```
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
```

Comment: If you have got your solution you can tick any of the answers as [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Below code will hide all the list items after the 25th list item.

**CSS**:

```
a:nth-of-type(1n+26)
{
  display:none;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ck0tks6x/

Answer (score 1):

Placing your list in list items is a good idea for accessibility and ease of styling also.

```css
.mylist li {
     display:none;
    }

    .mylist li:nth-child(1),
    .mylist li:nth-child(2),
    .mylist li:nth-child(3),
    /* through to */
    .mylist li:nth-child(25)
    {
     display:list-item;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="mylist">
    <li><a href="" class="onegame">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="onegame">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="onegame">...</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Instead of repeating same rule for every list element you can use a general formula. It will be a better solution if you are even using a list of 10000 elements. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `nth-child(n+x)`, for example:

```css
a:nth-child(n+3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">...</a>
```